# How can I stop iPhoto from uploading my videos to Facebook automatically?

Tags: imac, photos.app, facebook

When I visit my Facebook page I see several random videos that I didn't upload. iPhoto has done this several times to me- scared of what it will post with my knowledge! I try to close it and sometimes I can not even close the application because it is still synching with FB even if I click quit.

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 3):

When you add a Facebook to your mac, iPhoto can be set it to auto sync new photos.

To disable it change your Facebook password or search the iPhoto settings / Facebook permissions to disable auto sync. Alternately, removing the Facebook account from iPhoto or the OS (in the Mail, Contacts, Calendars preference pane) would do the trick as well.